# Cannot make symbolic links

Tags: apache, symlink, centos6, ln

I run a webpage on CentOS 6.6 by using Apache 2.4.10. My documentroot is /var/www/htdocs. Last month, because my disk became full, I added another disk in /disk1. I want to place large movie files in this directory and want visitors of my website to watch the videos. However, when I tried to make symbolic links from /var/www/htdocs/movies to /disk1/movies, I failed.
How can I make symbolic links on Apache? Is there another good way to realize what I want to do?

Comment: Could you add the command you ran and the error you got , to the question ?

Comment: "ln -s /disk1/movies/movie1.wav /var/www/htdocs/movies/movie1.wav" and the error_log says, "Symbolic link not allowed".

Comment: Have you set the 'FollowSymLinks' Option in httpd.conf ? Does you apache user has rx permission for the symlink target dir path.

Comment: Oh... I misconfigured FollowSymlinks in httpd.conf... Now it works. Is it better to configure in each .htaccess file?

Comment: You should configure it in httpd.conf , if you don't have access to it , update .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not now which I should modify httpd.cond or .htaccess.

Comment: No probs ,happy learning! Please accept the answer to close the question if it  helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have you set the 'FollowSymLinks' Option in httpd.conf and your apache user has rx permission for the symlink target dir path.